# is mongodb change stream a good approach for caching data with a low change rate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a set of settings value in my mongo database to store some data like password expiration time, message patterns, etc. and sometimes I want to change these values. The amount of data stored in this collection is less than 20 documents.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6260a31af04a8e177bc55c42"),
    "key" : "SMS_TEMPLATE_OTP",
    "value" : {
        "EXPIRATION_TIME" : 2,
        "MAX_COUNT" : 5,
        "MESSAGE" : "please enter {code} for verification"
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2024-01-19T20:16:29.682Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2024-01-20T04:30:12.333Z")
}
```

Inside my Node JS code, I have a singleton class that reads the values from the database once and puts them in a static variable then i read setting values from this variable and use them throughout the app.

```
import PrivateSettings from './private-setting';
export default class Setting {
  private static settings: PrivateSettings;
  constructor() {
    throw new Error('error');
  }
  static getSettings() {
    if (this.settings) {
      return this.settings;
    }
    this.settings = new PrivateSettings();
    return this.settings;
  }
}
```

```
import settingModel from '../../model/setting.model';

const getSettingData = async () => {
  const settings = await settingModel 
    .find({})
    .populate('createdBy', 'firstName lastName')
    .populate('lastChanges.updatedBy', 'firstName lastName')
    .sort('-createdAt')
    .lean();
  return settings;
};

export default class PrivateSettings  {
  private data: any;
  constructor() {}

  async init() {
    this.dataWithLastChanges = await getSettingData ();
  }

  public get(key: string): any {
    if (this.data) {
      return this.data.filter((item: any) => item.key === key)[0]?.value;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  public async watchChanges() {
    try {
      const changeStream = settingModel.watch();
      changeStream.on('change', async (next: any) => {
        await this.init();
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      // some code
    }
  }
}
```

I want to change the value of my static variable when one of the values of the settings collection changes.
Is it a good way to use change stream?

I have 3 production server nodes running my application and mongodb change stream is working fine. I just want to know if this method works well for caching my settings data or should i use different method like caching with redis.